# Write byte[](from plsql) into a file without saving into the physical path & ZIP it

Tags: java, arrays, plsql, spring-data-jpa, zip

Working with Spring Boot + Spring JPA + Web service. Currently I'm reading the byte[] from plsql, and writing it into a JSON file by specifying the local file path.

But the requirement is to write the byte[] into a file without actually saving the file into a physical path. Instead I need it in ZIP(And this Zip too should be downloaded or passed as it is in a response body). Is there any possibility of not storing these files at all?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there's no way you can generate a zip folder without storing it localy.

Here's what I'd do: create a zip folder in a temp directory (let's say temp/myzip_{timestamp}), return it to the user and then remove it from the temp directory.